# Does there necessarily exist such a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-continuation

This is an old qual problem I'm working on: Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function. Does there necessarily exist a holomorphic function $g: \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(x)-g(x)$ vanishes to infinite order at $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$ in $[0,1]$?

To be honest, maybe I couldn't make much progress on this. I tried to write Laurent series for $0$, and using the given condition, tried to conclude that if such a $g$ exists, it must be analytically extended to $0$ too. Then, I tried to find such an $f$ that cannot be extended analytically to the whole plane, but failed. But, my reasoning here might be very false, I'm not sure. I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: What does you means by "vanishes to infinite order at 0"? That $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^n} \to 0$ ?

Comment: @Tryss Yes. $ $

Comment: @ Tryss: Yes, I also understood that way.

Comment: If you can show that $g$ must be entire then the answer is no. Because of the following fact: If $a_n$ is any sequence there exists an infinitely differentiable $f$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)=a_n$. But showing that $g$ must be entire is not entirely clear to me. It's clear that $g$ cannnot have a _pole_ at the origin, but...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Thanks. Yes, it's not clear to me neither, actually. It was just a try. I see your point though.

Comment: In fact we _can't_ show that $g$ must be entire! Say $g(z)=e^{-1/z}$ and $f=0$. Then $f-g$ vanishes to infinite order as $z\to0$ within $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Nice example, thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Do you have a link to that result? (given a sequence $a_n$, there is a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function s.t $f^{(n)}(0) = a_n$)

Comment: @Farnight That's a theorem of Borel I believe.

Comment: @Farnight It's an exercise somewhere in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, and we can relax the condition on $f.$ We need only assume $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb {C}$ is continuous. We then consider  $\tilde {f}(t) = f(1/t),$ which is continuous on $[1,\infty).$ Let's extend $\tilde {f}$ to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb {R}.$

Now I pull out a big gun, Carleman's theorem (one of them anyway): Suppose $\varphi :\mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {C}$ is continuous, and $\epsilon:\mathbb {R}\to (0,\infty)$ is continuous. Then there is an entire function $g$ such that

$$|g(t)-\varphi (t)|<\epsilon(t), t \in \mathbb {R}.$$

That's a beautiful result. Anyway, let $\epsilon(t) = e^{-t^2}.$ Then Carleman says there is an entire $g$ with

$$ |\tilde {f}(t)-g(t)|< e^{-t^2}, t \in \mathbb {R}.$$

Flip back to $(0,1]$ and we have

$$|f(t)-g(1/t)|< e^{-1/t^2}, t \in (0,1],$$

which is more than enough in our problem (note $g(1/z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb {C}\setminus \{0\}).$

Perhaps the $f\in C^\infty([0,1])$ assumption is a red herring, or perhaps there is a more elementary approach to the problem at hand that uses smoothness.

Comment: Excellent! I don't recall ever seeing Carleman's theorem before - now I have to think about how to prove it. No hints please... I can almost imagine a proof based on Runge's theorem and some iterative construction...